# Stop execution of a Sequelize promise in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm new to the world of promises and I'm not sure I fully understand how to use them in some cases.

Sequelize recently added support for promises, which really makes my code more readable. A typical scenario is to avoid handling errors several times in infinite callbacks.

The snippet below always return `204`, while I'd like it to return `404` when the photo cannot be found.

Is there a way to tell Sequelize to "stop" the execution of the promise chain after sending 404? Note that `res.send` is asynchronous so it does not stop the execution.

```
// Find the original photo
Photo.find(req.params.id).then(function (photo) {
    if (photo) {
        // Delete the photo in the db
        return photo.destroy();
    } else {
        res.send(404);
        // HOW TO STOP PROMISE CHAIN HERE?
    }
}).then(function () {
    res.send(204);
}).catch(function (error) {
    res.send(500, error);
});
```

Of course this example is trivial and could easily be written with callbacks. But in most cases the code can become way longer.

Comment: What you need is a way to mark the promise as resolved at that point. I am not familiar with sequelize, but I assume there must be a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks Edwin. The only thing I know is that Sequelize uses Bluebird. However, I don't see anything in their API that allows me do stop a promise chain.

Comment: If you `throw` inside your `then` handler, that will reject the chain. There's also an (open issue)[https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/272] to automatically reject the find call if not result is found. You could voice your support there if you need the feature

Comment: That sounds great! I will add a comment today. The throw seems to be a good fallback for now too. Thanks for you answer :)

Comment: Ok I posted into a related pull request and got my final answer. Looks like the best solution is to `throw` inside the `then` as you suggested. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/934

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your promise chains don't necessarily have to be linear.  You can "branch off" and create a separate promise chain for the success case, chaining on as many `.then()`'s as you need to, while having a separate (shorter) promise chain for the failure case.

Conceptually, that looks like this:

```
         Photo.find
          /     \
         /       \
    (success)   (failure)
       /           \
      /             \
photo.destroy    res.send(404)
     |
     |
res.send(204)
```

And in the actual code, that looks like this:

```
// Find the original photo
Photo.find(req.params.id).then(function (photo) {
    if (photo) {
        // Delete the photo in the db
        return photo.destroy().then(function () {
            res.send(204);
        });
    } else {
        res.send(404);
    }
}).catch(function (error) {
    res.send(500, error);
});
```

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I ended up doing. I was expecting Sequelize to simply reject my `find()` promise in order to avoid having too much nested code.
Last question: do you know if I need to add a `catch()` for the `destroy()` promise too? Or it will handled by the catch at the end? Thanks!

Comment: @PedroCheckos, unless you define a separate `catch()` block within your `Photo.destroy()` promise chain, any unhandled exceptions should "bubble up" to the outer `catch()` block.

Comment: Awesome, that's all I needed to know! Thanks a lot for the tips :)

Comment: @PedroCheckos, I just stumbled upon this and remembered this question: [Promise Cancellation in bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#cancellation). (Note that bluebird is what sequelize.js appears to be using under the hood.)  I didn't know that "cancellable promises" were a thing. Further research also led to this question, which has some good information: [Status of cancellable promises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781434/status-of-cancellable-promises). Perhaps this will give you some more ideas to try.