# Cancel a delayed Bluebird promise

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, cancellation

How to reject a delayed Promise:

```
const removeDelay = Promise.delay(5000).then(() => {
    removeSomething();
});

//Undo event - if it is invoked before 5000 ms, then undo deleting
removeDelay.reject(); // reject is not a method
```

Answer (score 8):

**Bluebird v3**

We no longer need to declare a Promise as 'cancellable' ([documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html)):

> no setup code required to make cancellation work

Simply call `cancel` on a Promise:

```
const promise = new Promise(function (_, _, onCancel) {
    onCancel(function () {
        console.log("Promise cancelled");
    });
});

promise.cancel(); //=> "Promise cancelled"
```

As you may have noticed, the `cancel` method no longer accepts the reason for cancellation as an argument. Logic required on cancellation can be declared within a function given to `onCancel`, the third argument given to a Promise constructor executor. Or within a `finally` callback, as it is also not considered an error when a Promise is cancelled.

Revised example:

```
const removeDelay = Promise
    .delay(5000)
    .then(() => removeSomething());

removeDelay.cancel();
```

______

**Pre Bluebird v3**

Take a look at the documentation for [`Promise#cancellable`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#cancellation):

> By default, a promise is not cancellable. A promise can be marked as cancellable with `.cancellable()`. A cancellable promise can be cancelled if it's not resolved. Cancelling a promise propagates to the farthest cancellable ancestor of the target promise that is still pending, and rejects that promise with the given reason, or [`CancellationError`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#cancellationerror) by default.

We can use it like so:

```
const removeDelay = Promise
    .delay(5000)
    .cancellable() // Declare this Promise as 'cancellable'
    .then(() => removeSomething());
    .catch(err => console.log(err)); // => 'Reason for cancel'

removeDelay.cancel('Reason for cancel');
```

Comment: this answer is outdated - refer to the documentation instead

Answer (score 0):

Bluebird v3

```
import * as Promise from 'bluebird';
Promise.config({cancellation: true});

const delayPromise = Promise
    .delay(5000)
    .then(() => doSomething());

delayPromise.cancel();
```