# how to use .cancel() with bluebird

Tags: promise, bluebird

document API here  http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html

i try it in my demo,but doesn't work

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var a = require('./a');
var b = require('./b');

var cancelPromise = Promise.resolve();
cancelPromise.cancel();
cancelPromise = a.fnA()
  .then(function() {
    return b.fnB();
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log('done');
  })
  .finally(function() {
    if (cancelPromise.isCancelled()) {
      console.log('canceled');
    }
    console.log('end');
  });
```

so how to use this method?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You are setting `cancelPromise` to a dummy promise... then you are cancelling that dummy promise, and then setting `cancelPromise` to something else.

Comment: The cancellation feature is by **default turned off**, you can enable it using `Promise.config`.

Comment: but this code from the example of API,i'd added `Promise.config` ,but it doesn't work.

Comment: ref to [Cancel a delayed Bluebird promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71302408/6318705)

Answer (score 5):

To use `.cancel()`, first you need to turn `cancellation` **ON** and only then call function `.cancel()`

If your work with bluebird below 3, your code should look something like that:

```
var mainAction = a.fnA()
.cancellable() // => cancellation turned on
.then(function() {
    return b.fnB();
})
.then(function() {
    console.log('done');
})
.catch(function( err ){  // => 'Reason for cancel'
   console.error(err); 
})
.finally(function() {  
    console.log('end');
});

mainAction.cancel('Reason for cancel');
```

And if you work with bluebird 3 and above, the code should look like this:

```
var successfulFetch = false, mainAction = a.fnA()
.then(function() {
   return b.fnB();
})
.then(function() {
   console.log('done');
}).finally(function() {
  if(!successfulFetch){
    console.error('Reason for cancel');
  }
  console.log('end');
});
mainAction.cancel();
```

Also I suggest you to take a look at this post: [Cancel a delayed Bluebird promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872203/cancel-a-delayed-bluebird-promise/32872276#32872276)

which was really helpful for me, when I had a similar problem

Comment: that's mean i can't cancel it in any step i want?

Comment: You can do this in any step. You need to add: `mainAction.cancel()` where you want cancel promise