# Cancel a fetch request in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

Is there any way to abort a fetch request on react-native app ?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { data: null };

  componentDidMount = () =>
    fetch('http://www.example.com')
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }))
      .catch(error => {
        throw error; 
      });

  cancelRequest = () => {
   //???
  };

  render = () => <div>{this.state.data ? this.state.data : 'loading'}</div>;
}
```

i tried the `abort` function from `AbortController` class but it's not working !!

```
...
abortController = new window.AbortController();

cancelRequest =  () => this.abortController.abort();

componentDidMount = () =>
        fetch('http://www.example.com', { signal: this.abortController.signal })
          ....
```

Any help please !

Comment: ref to [Cancel a delayed Bluebird promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71302408/6318705)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best solution is using rxjs observables + axios/fetch instead of promises, abort a request => unsubscribe an observable :

```
import Axios from "axios";
import {
    Observable
} from "rxjs";

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    subs = null;

    doStuff = () => {
        let observable$ = Observable.create(observer => {
            Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', {}, {})
                .then(response => {
                    observer.next(response.data);
                    observer.complete();
                })
        });

        this.subs = observable$.subscribe({
            next: data => console.log('[data] => ', data),
            complete: data => console.log('[complete]'),
        });

    }

    cancel = () =>
        if (this.subs) this.subs.unsubscribe()

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.subs) this.subs.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

That is it :)

Comment: That does not cancel the underlying axios request. Just the subscription to the result.

Answer (score 15):

You don't need any polyfill anymore for abort a request in React Native 0.60 [changelog](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Here is a quick example from the [doc](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/5e36b0c6eb2494cefd11907673aa018831526750/RNTester/js/XHRExampleAbortController.js) of react-native:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
*/

'use strict';

const React = require('react');
const {Alert, Button, View} = require('react-native');

class XHRExampleAbortController extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  _timeout: any;

  _submit(abortDelay) {
    clearTimeout(this._timeout);
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/', {
      signal: abortController.signal,
    })
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(res => Alert.alert(res))
      .catch(err => Alert.alert(err.message));
    this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          abortController.abort();
    }, abortDelay);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this._timeout);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Abort before response"
          onPress={() => {
            this._submit(0);
          }}
        />
        <Button
          title="Abort after response"
          onPress={() => {
            this._submit(5000);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = XHRExampleAbortController;
```

Answer (score 8):

I've written quite a bit actually about this subject.
You can also find the first issue about the **OLD** lack of AbortController in React Native opened by me [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18115)

**The support landed in RN 0.60.0** and you can find on my blog [an article about this](https://giacomocerquone.com/blog/aborting-fetch-react-native) and [another one that will give you a simple code](https://giacomocerquone.com/blog/fetch-wrapper) to get you started on making abortable requests (and more) in React Native too. It also implements a little polyfill for non supporting envs (RN < 0.60 for example).

Comment: It's actually better to put the code here and additionally add a link to your article for more in-depth understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can Actually achieve this by installing this polyfill [abortcontroller-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abortcontroller-polyfill) 
Here is a quick example of cancelling requests:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import 'abortcontroller-polyfill';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  state = { todos: [] };

  controller = new AbortController();

  doStuff = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',{
      signal: this.controller.signal
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(todos => {
      alert('done');
      this.setState({ todos })
    })
    .catch(e => alert(e.message));
    alert('calling cancel');
    this.controller.abort()
  }


  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Button title="Do stuff" onPress={() => { this.doStuff(); }} /> 
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

So basically in this example, once you click the 'doStuff' button, the request is immediately cancelled and you never get the 'done' alert. To be sure, it works, try and comment out these lines and click the button again:

```
alert('calling cancel');
this.controller.abort()
```

This time you will get the 'done' alert.

This is a simple example of hoe you can cancel a request using fetch in react native, feel free to adopt this to your own use case.

Here is a link to a demo on snackexpo https://snack.expo.io/@mazinoukah/fetch-cancel-request

hope it helps :)

Comment: this is not working, i get this error message : Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
[AbortError: Aborted]

Comment: From the docs:- This "polyfill" doesn't actually close the connection when the request is aborted, but it will call .catch() with err.name == 'AbortError' instead of .then()