# React/Firebase user registration promises - Can't call setState on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
firebase.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then( data => {
        const {user} = data;
        if (user) {
            user.updateProfile({displayName: name})
            .then(() => {
                // when i try to change state for reload, it says its unmounted??
                this.forceUpdate()
            })
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({errors: error.message})
    })
```

Where after the user is created, it also updates their displayName. I want to force a refresh/state change since I have a component waiting for the displayName. However it gives me the error `Can't call setState on an unmounted component...`.

Can someone explain the reason for the error and what would be the best way to handle this?

edit. this code is being called when user submits a signup form

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Comment: You are not canceling your request when Component unmount, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56139976/2308005

Comment: Have you tried using state to re-render instead of forcing it?

Comment: @Anthony I'm calling this when the user submits a signup form

Comment: @joseluismurillorios yes, i also tried setting state, but I get the same error

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Thanks for the resource, since I am only calling this when user submits the form, do I still need to cancel the request since this codes doesn't run continuously? Also, would you be able to show me how the code in componentWillUnmount would look like in this case?

Comment: Are you using a form with method post?