# refactor promise and promise.all with async await of es2017

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have a working version of a photo upload handler but I would want to see how it work with async await. Before anything below is my working code using promise.

```
onChangePhotos = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    let files = e.target.files

    if(files.length === 0) { return }

    const allow_photos_length = this.state.selectedAlbum.photos.length + files.length
    if(allow_photos_length > this.state.maxPhoto) {
      alert(`Maximum only ${maxPhoto} photos per album!`)
      return
    }

    this.setState({
      uploading_photo: true
    })

    let promises = []
    for(const file of files){
      promises.push(UploadApi.uploadPhoto('company', file))
    }

    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(responses => {

      let next_photos = []
      for(const [index, response] of responses.entries()) {
        const { upload_id, url } = response

        next_photos.push({photo_id: upload_id, url})

        if(responses.length === index + 1){
          this.setState({
            uploading_photo: false
          })
        }
      }

      this.setState({
        selectedAlbum: {
          ...this.state.selectedAlbum,
          photos: [
            ...this.state.selectedAlbum.photos,
            ...next_photos
          ]
        }
      })

    })
    .catch(err =>{
      this.setState({ uploading_photo: false })
      alert('failed to upload! Error: ' + err)
    })
  }
```

I convert it to async await, webpack did not show any error, but when I try to test on my webapp, found that `this` is not defined when I do `console.log(this)`.

Below is my async await attempt:

```
onChangePhotos = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    let files = e.target.files

    if(files.length === 0) { return }

    this.setState({
      uploading: true
    })

    let promises = []
    for(const file of files){
      const uploadPhotoPromise = await UploadApi.singlePhoto(file)
      promises.push(uploadPhotoPromise)
    }

    try {

      const responses = await Promise.all(promises)

      let next_photos = []
      for(const [index, response] of responses.entries()) {
        const { upload_id, url } = response

        next_photos.push({photo_id: upload_id, url})

        if(responses.length === index + 1){
          this.setState({
            uploading: false
          })
        }
      }

      this.setState({
        selectedAlbum: {
          ...this.state.selectedAlbum,
          photos: [
            ...this.state.selectedAlbum.photos,
            ...next_photos
          ]
        }
      })

    } catch(err) {
      this.setState({ uploading: false })
      alert('failed to upload! Error: ' + err)
    }
  }
```

What's the problem?

Comment: "*I got error that look like this3 is not defined.*" - what? There's no `this3` in your code anywhere.

Comment: @Bergi I don't know that's what I got, I don't see other error than that.

Comment: Are you using a transpiler? In what line do you get the error?

Comment: @Bergi I found the problem. this is not defined when I do console.log(this). I have this in my .babelrc `["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true
    }]`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the error is suppose to mean, because of lack of information, but your promises array has no promises, because you already use `await`:

I suggest changing this:

```
let promises = []
for(const file of files){
  const uploadPhotoPromise = await UploadApi.singlePhoto(file)
  promises.push(uploadPhotoPromise)
}
```

to:

```
const promises = [];

for(const file of files){
  promises.push(UploadApi.singlePhoto(file))
}
```

Comment: isn't it the same thing? uploadPhotoPromise is a promise and it got pushed into promises array, no?

Comment: you are using `await` in front of the `UploadApi.singlePhoto`. This means that the return value is not a promise, but the resolved value from the promise

Comment: files.map is not a function.

Comment: Ah files is a `FileList`. Didn't see that, I'll update my answer