# Abort await request-promise

Tags: node.js, request-promise

Is it possible to abort a request while its pending?

Code:

```
var response = await request({uri :”https://www.google.com”})
```

How would I go about aborting this request?(Not talking about setting timeout)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Promise - is it possible to force cancel a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233302/promise-is-it-possible-to-force-cancel-a-promise)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call: `.cancel`

```
const req = request({uri :”https://www.google.com”})

req.cancel();
```

Have in mind that it will be tricky to use with `await`, unless it's happening in another part of the code. If you show as a fully working example, and when you want to abort the request it will be easy to give you an example.

---

Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/request/request-promise#cancel):

> This method cancels the request using Bluebird's cancellation feature.

When `.cancel()` is called:

- the promise will neither be resolved nor rejected and the
- request is aborted.

Comment: What would be the approach if I want to cancel after - lets say 5 seconds after `request()` is made with `await`?