# Asynchronous "Task" Result Code Flow in C# vs JavaScript (or TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript

As a general software concept, some async operation has the ability to take three different "paths":

1. The operation successfully worked and we continue execution
2. The operation failed and the system threw an exception
3. The operation was cancelled by either the system (a timeout) or by user interaction

In C# we can handle these 3 different "paths" like so:

```
try
{
    await myService.doAsync();
}
catch(TaskCanceledException ex)
{
   // Here, we know that somehow the Task was cancelled. Whether that is caused by something like
   // a timeout or a user explicitly performed some operation to cancel the Task
   // This might be apart of some actual business logic and so I want to handle it differently than
   // a general exception
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // This means something went wrong in the downstream code and I probably
    // want to log an error and do something else or 'throw' again so upstream 
    // execution can handle the failure as well
}
```

However, trying to do this in JavaScript or TypeScript doesn't work as elegantly from what I have seen since we don't have the ability to check types which means we also can't cascade `catch` blocks like we can in C#:

```
try
{
    await myService.doAsync();
}
catch(e)
{
    if(e instanceof TaskCancelledError) {
        // Here, we know that somehow the Task was cancelled. Whether that is caused by something like
        // a timeout or a user explicitly performed some operation to cancel the Task
        // This might be apart of some actual business logic and so I want to handle it differently than
        // a general exception
    }else{
        // This means something went wrong in the downstream code and I probably
        // want to log an error and do something else or 'throw' again so upstream 
        // execution can handle the failure as well
    }
}

class TaskCancelledError extends Error {
    constructor() {
        super("The task was cancelled");
    }
}
```

Is what I laid out above the only way to achieve parity in features between TypeScript (JavaScript) and C#?  I could do this, but it just felt a little hacky.

As a side note, would it be at all possible to change TypeScript to support this kind of structure of `catch` blocks, but that TS would compile into the code we see above?

Comment: Related to the cancellation part of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233302/promise-is-it-possible-to-force-cancel-a-promise How are you wanting to trigger cancellation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  That is the proper way to catch a specific type of exception in both Javascript and Typescript.

C# has a broad standard library with support for cancellation tokens and consistent use of TaskCanceledException.  TypeScript does not.  Those CancellationTokens have to be kept track of and it’s a fair amount of work.  Many TypeScript async primitives (e.g. interval, fetch, xhr, etc.) support some kind of abort / cancel but they all do it in different ways and they don’t always throw at all.

It would be possible to change TypeScript to support this but I don’t think that will happen.  There was discussion on it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8677) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9999) bad they chose not to support this feature.

Comment: NIT: Cancellation tokens are separate from C# (the language, just as such would be from TS) - there is no special language support here, just library (as opposed to async methods, which are largely compiler magic and separate from cancellation) which has to be uniformly used and exposed. Checking types is also orthogonal to the existence of CT. The NIT aside, CT (as in .NET) relies on some special runtime (not language) handling not present in standard JS implementations.