# Correct way to cleanup useEffect with Promise

Tags: reactjs, promise, use-effect

I have `useEffect` callback where I'm fetching some data from several API. To do that I'm using `Promise` and my code looks like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
   const fetchAllData = async () => {
      const resourceOne = new Promise((resolve) => {
         // fetching data from resource one and changing some states
      })
      const resourceTwo = new Promise((resolve) => {
         // fetching data from resource two and changing some states
      })
      const resourceThree = new Promise((resolve) => {
         // fetching data from resource three and changing some states
      })

      await Promise.all([resourceOne, resourceTwo, resourceThree])
      .then(() => {
         // changing some states
      })
   }

   return fetchAllData()
},[])
```

How I understand in this situation `useEffect` unmount before fetching all data and then gives me an warning

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

So how to write correctly cleanup code to avoid this warning?

Comment: Can you use `AbortController`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65805464/5385381

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a boolean and toggle it in the cleanup function (the function that is returned in the callback passed to `useEffect`)

```
useEffect(() => {
    let shouldUpdate = true;

    const fetchAllData = () => {
       const resourceOne = new Promise((resolve) => {
          // fetching data from resource one and changing some states
       })
       const resourceTwo = new Promise((resolve) => {
          // fetching data from resource two and changing some states
       })
       const resourceThree = new Promise((resolve) => {
          // fetching data from resource three and changing some states
       })
 
       Promise.all([resourceOne, resourceTwo, resourceThree])
        .then(() => {
           if(shouldUpdate) {
               // update state
           }
       })
    }
 
    fetchAllData()
    return () => {
        shouldUpdate = false;
    }
 },[])
```

If the component is unmounted the cleanup function will be called and `shouldUpdate` will change to false. When the promises resolve, the state will not update as `shouldUpdate` is no longer true.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [`Abort Signal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal), to abort all promises,

```js
const controller = new AbortController();

const fetch = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // fetch data here
  controller.signal.addEventListener('abort', () => reject());
});

controller.abort(); // promise is cancelled
```

Translating to your use-case:

```js
const controller = new AbortController();
useEffect(() => {
   const fetchAllData = async () => {
      const resourceOne = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         // fetching data from resource one and changing some states
          controller.signal.addEventListener('abort', () => reject());
      })
      const resourceTwo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         // fetching data from resource two and changing some states
          controller.signal.addEventListener('abort', () => reject());
      })
      const resourceThree = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         // fetching data from resource three and changing some states
          controller.signal.addEventListener('abort', () => reject());
      })

      await Promise.all([resourceOne, resourceTwo, resourceThree])
      .then(() => {
         // changing some states
      })
   }

   fetchAllData();

   return () => {
        controller.abort(); // all promise are cancelled where 'abort' listener is specified
    }
},[])
```

And call `controller.abort()` to cancel one or more number of promises where you included the event listener when the component unmounts.

When `abort()` is called, the promise rejects with an `AbortError`, so you can listen to that and handle aborted rejects differently.