# React Link to same component, has subcomponent using the wrong version of passed state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Below I have a SubComponent and a MainComponent. This is meant to be a page that displays an image collection. In the Subcomponent using the `onclick()` event you can swap between pictures in that collection. **The MainComponent will also display links to other collections, but these are links to the same component itself.**

The problem is that when I click the link to go to a new collection, my SubComponent will often use the outdated `mainImage` to set the imageList state. It will fetch the correct response (data) however and also `currentImage` will still use the correct version of `mainPicture` and be set correctly. So in other words only the first image of the "image chooser" will use the outdated `mainImage` and be set incorrectly.

SubComponent.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import my_client
import stockimage

const Subcomponent = ({ mainPicture, my_url, identifier }) => {

    const [ imagesList, setImageList ] = useState([])

    const baseImageUrl = `${my_url}`

    const [ currentImage, setCurrentImage ] = useState(`main/${mainPicture}`)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchList = async () => {
            const { data, error } = await my_client
              .fetch(`${identifier}`)
            if (data) {
              setImageList([`main/${mainPicture}`, ...(data.map(obj => `sub/${obj.name}`))])
            }
            if (error) {
              console.log(error)
              setImageList([])
            }
        }

        fetchList()
        console.log("fetched")

        setCurrentImage(`main/${mainPicture}`)
    }, [identifier, mainPicture])

    return (
        <div>
            {mainPicture ? <img src={`${baseImageUrl}/${currentImage}`} /> : <img src={stockimage} />}
            { imagesList && imagesList.length > 1 &&
            <div>
                { imagesList.map((item, item_index) => (
                    <div key={item_index}>
                        <img src={`${baseImageUrl}/${item}`} onClick={() => setCurrentImage(item)}/>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default SubComponent
```

MainComponent.js (simplified)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import SubComponent from './SubComponent'
import Context from './Context'
import my_client
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import fetchLinks from './Functions.js'

const MainComponent = () => {

  const location = useLocation()
  
  const [ mainPicture, setMainPicture ] = 
  useState(location.state?.paramPicture || null)
  const { identifier } = useParams()
  const my_url = useContext(Context)

  const [ links, setLinks ] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
      const my_fetch = async () => {
          const { data, error } = await my_client
            .fetch(`${identifier}/main`)
          if (data) {
            setMainImage(data.mainImage)
            setLinks(data.otherImagesData)
          }
          if (error) {
            console.log(error)
          }
      }

      if (location.state.paramPicture) {
          setMainPicture(location.state.paramPicture)
          fetchLinks(identifier, setLinks)
      } else {
          my_fetch()
      }
  }, [identifier, location.state.paramPicture])

  return (
    <div>
        <SubComponent mainPicture={mainPicture} my_url={my_url} identifier={identifier} />
        {links.map(item => (<Link to={`/view/${item.link}`} state={{ paramPicture: item.picture }}>))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MainComponent
```

App.js (router)

```js
return (
<div className="App">
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/view' element={<View />} />
        <Route path='/view/:link' element={<MainComponent />} />
    </Switch>
</div>
)
```

Comment: You seem to have shared an incomplete [mcve] that is missing the relevant React-Router-DOM code and logic. Please [edit] to include a complete code example so we can see what you are working with. What do you want the source of truth to be, the URL path parameters, or some local React component state?

Comment: @DrewReese Only identifier is determined by the url. The state that gets passed via the Link is supposed to be the truth, but if there is no paramState (eg the user tried to go to that image directly and not via a similar image) then it should fetch it. I tried to answer you question as best I could, but I might be misunderstanding it. I will edit the question, although it's very large and hard to include everyhting.

Comment: Sorry, I meant which of the route state or local state do you want the source of truth to be. Is `MainComponent` effectively linking to itself, i.e. is `MainComponent` rendered on `path="/view/:link"`? It's unclear what you are linking and passing state to.

Comment: @DrewReese The short answer is yes. I will edit my question. ```<Route path='/view/:link' element={<MainComponent />} />```

Comment: Just use the route state directly instead of trying to store it in local state and dealing with synchronicity issues.

Comment: @DrewReese The problem is that this state won't always be available. This route state is only available when you link from a page where this image is already fetched. In my code for example the images(data) have already been fetched to use it's data for the links. However let's say the user types the url of that imagecollection direclty into search bar, then ```location.state.paramPicture``` will be empty and I will need to fetch.

I assume you mean I should use useLocation? If there is a way to combine this and still fix the issue I just mentioned, then could you please show me?

Comment: Isn't that still the case with your current existing code? If a user manually navigates to `"/view/someLinkValue"` the `location.state` will be undefined and the `mainPicture` state will be initialized to the same value, e.g. undefined? A user needs to click one of the links that `MainComponent` renders in order to navigate with the `paramPicture` in route state. Am I just not understanding your code and use case?

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited the code in my question since my initial post. As you mentioned the code was incomplete and so I updated it. This was indeed missing in the initial version. I have added:

```
if (location.state.paramPicture) {
          setMainPicture(location.state.paramPicture)
          fetchLinks(setLinks)
      } else {
          my_fetch()
      }
```
in my MainComponent.

Answer (score 1):

There is essentially a lot of state duplication. The key issue is most likely that you are copying the history state item `paramPicture` inside local component state by passing it as the initial value of a `useState` hook.

That means when `MainComponent` mounts, whatever this value was at that time is captured and copied into `mainPicture`. When you go to a new collection, via the link with the new `paramPicture` in the links `state` prop, the `MainComponent` component is only *rerendered* and not torn down. This means that `mainPicture` will retain the old value.

However, storing this in a `useState` is not needed in the first place. There is no point since the value is freely available from the history state. Copying data into local component state (`useState`) is a common source of bugs since now you are unnecessarily having to manage code to keep it in sync (which, regardless, is missing here anyway).

That said you can't just reference `location.state?.paramPicture` directly all over the code, because it is part of the base web API, and React wouldn't know that it changed so it also would not know that it needs to re-render.

However `useLocation`, does know this, because it internally hooks into page nav events.

First import `useLocation`:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Using this hook is like reading from `location.state?.paramPicture`, apart from the react component will automatically rerender when that history state changes.

Change:

```
const [ mainPicture, setMainPicture ] = useState(location.state?.paramPicture || null)
```

To

```
const { state: { mainPicture = null } } = useLocation()
```

Comment: The value won't always be available in the history state. The state will only be passed the the url if you access it via a page where that image is already fetched. If you want to access it by just typing in the url manually, then you won't find anything in ```location.state?.paramPicture```. I have edited the question to include how I address this. Also I would need a setMainPicture to use in my useEffect, because as you said the component doesn't remount, it just rerenders.

Comment: Do note that ```mainPicture``` does get updated correctly and ```CurrentImage``` that also relies on the passing of ```mainPicture``` to the SubComponent also got updated correctly.

Comment: Right. the call to `setMainPicture` was missing, it looks like you have now edited that in. However, it wont work as you expect. Theres quite a few duplication issues here -- but one thing at a time. You are using `location.state.paramPicture` now in the useEffect. That wont trigger the effect when location changes since `location` is a global on `window` outside of reacts remit. You absolutely need `useLocation` here instead of referencing that global.

Comment: As for how you manage that it can come from the URL to the state -- this is solved by a `useMemo` that returns the state item if it exists, and the URL parma if it does not. It is not solved by using a new `useState` item. It *can* be made to work that way. But you just greatly increase the surface area for bugs by now having to manually keep something in sync.

Comment: Worth mentioning it may appear to update now, without `useLocation`, but it would do so only accidentally. Essentially if something else triggers a rerender and now it reads the new value. But that is relying on bugs.

Comment: @adsy FWIW I was assuming OP was using the `useLocation` hook and that `location.state?.paramPicture` was from the `location` object it returns. I think the location object you are referring to would need to be qualified from the `window` object, e.g `window.location`, etc.  I still think OP hasn't included a complete [mcve]. Otherwise, I agree with your answer as this is basically what I was also telling OP to do... to just reference the `useLocation` `location.state` object directly instead of messing with keeping states synchrononized.

Comment: @ Drew Reese -- yeh i thought so too potentially, but it's impossible to see the wood through the trees. The problem is possibly stale promises from prev renders, but first, the whole thing needs cleaning up to remove the incorrect state copying at multiple levels and properly use memoisation instead. Im gonna edit my post encapsulating all the above shortly.

Comment: One second thoughts for sure we need to see the structure of the response data, for all the fetch calls, including that which is inside of `fetchLinks`.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, my ```const location = useLocation()``` was indeed missing, apologies.

Are you suggesting I should just use ```location.state.paramPicture || mainPicture``` whenever I used mainPicture in my SubComponent. With mainPicture being only the result of fetch and not storing the route state in. Or would you suggest I store the router state in mainPicture (as adsy's answer above suggests) and then just update that router state directly when I fetch? (I would fetch when I see that the router state is empty.)

Comment: @adsy "The problem is possibly stale promises from prev renders" - Yes, this was my best guess as well. fetchLinks shouldn't be the problem, I can tell for sure this gets set correctly and it's nothing more than a fetch from my backend client. It returns the link to that collection and the url for the thumbnail image. ```My_fetch()``` returns the same in ```.otherImages``` and fetches the thumbnailUrl for the mainPicture in ```.mainImage``` as well. ```FetchList()``` returns a list of urls for all the other pictures, not including the thumbnail picture. Or are you asking to log the responses?

Comment: @adsy I have added ```const location = useLocation()```, this was indeed missing. The ```location``` varaible was using ```useLocaiton()``` all along but I forgot to add it. I can see how this caused a lot of confusion and waste a lot of time. Apologies for this oversight.

Comment: No worries, so with that change, you are still seeing the problem? We can add guards to the `then()` callback on the promises to no-op like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554978/correct-way-to-cleanup-useeffect-with-promise. That prevents stale promises that were actually launched based on old values, then later resolving out of order. When that happens it potentially overwrites the new vlaues with stale ones. But guard like above can stop this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using my router state directly, so I wouldn't need to rely on my MainComponent's `const [ mainPicture, setMainPicture ] = useState()` and don't have to update that manually, when I simply have a more relaible router state available.

```js
setImageList([`main/${mainPicture}`, ...(data.map(obj => `sub/${obj.name}`))])
```

becomes -->

```js
setImageList([`main/${location.state?.paramPicture || mainPicture}`, ...(data.map(obj => `sub/${obj.name}`))])
```

and I passed my location from my MainComponent to my SubComponent.