# Is it possible to completely unmount component with all it's async tasks when using React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I want to cleanup react tree and abort all of it's asynchronous tasks. The react tree is rendered using `render` function of React Testing Library. I know that you can use `cleanup` function to unmount react tree but that doesn't cancel all the asynchronous tasks.

The motivation: I am calling backend API to clean db after each test. If I don't remove all the async tasks after a test finishes, some API calls might occur after cleaning the db causing errors.

Comment: Do you mean you want to cancel all pending async tasks such as promises?

Comment: @slideshowp2 Yes, all promises.

Answer (score 1):

This is a universal issue with javascript and promises, not specific to testing-library. To do this you would need to add additional logic wrapping your promises that fire when the component unmounts.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30235261/3430412).