# In a list of Promises, is there a way to kill the other Promises once anyone is resolved? or do we have alternative to Promise here?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have tried using Promise.race(), but in this case too if one of the Promise is resolved the other Promises keep on running.

Is there a way to stop other processes from running once one of them wins.

I do not want other processes to keep running and using system resources.

I am open to use other ways instead of promises to implement this.

In practice PromiseA is waiting for PromiseZ (I am using the following code to mock similar behaviour)

Since I know now after running PromiseA that PromiseB is not required, I want to stop PromiseB

Is there any better way to do this?

```
var promiseList = [];

var flag = false;


function PromiseA() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(flag)
            flag = true;
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}


function PromiseB() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (flag === true) {
                console.log('checking')
                console.log('flag is:' + flag)
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        }, 7000);
    });
}



promiseList.push(PromiseA());
promiseList.push(PromiseB());




Promise.all(promiseList);
```

Comment: The [`Promise` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) does not support cancellation.

Comment: @jsejcksn I am open to explore other ways instead of Promise

Comment: @AbdullahKhilji If you share your actual code, then a potential alternative suggestion can be made. Currently, we can only guess what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Promise - is it possible to force cancel a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233302/promise-is-it-possible-to-force-cancel-a-promise)

Comment: @jsejcksn have add some code snippet for some context

Comment: @AbdullahKhilji Thanks for clarifying. I've provided [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72422205/438273) based on the code you've shown.

Answer (score 2):

According to ECMAScript specification you can not cancel an ongoing promise.

However you can abort a fetch request using `AbortController` which be used not only for fetch but also for other asynchronous tasks.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort
- https://javascript.info/fetch-abort

> Is there a way to stop other processes from running once one of them wins.

You can chain the expensive computation in a way to run once the earlier promise is resolved.

If you want to cut down on server resources you can run each promise one by one or chain them.

```js
const promiseA = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('Some value'));
const promiseB = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('Other value'));

Promise.resolve(10)
  .then(promiseA).catch(promiseB)
  .then(val => console.log(val))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Is there any alternative to Promise that could work here?

Comment: I think you are trying to prevent unnecessary server work. Only option I can think of sending one by one rather than race.

Comment: If you're talking about `Promise` itself, there's no way to do that. But if it's something like `fetch`, there's a `AbortController`.

Comment: * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort

* https://javascript.info/fetch-abort

Comment: Why AbortControllers are better than declaring global variables?

Answer (score 1):

Following up on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72421849/in-a-list-of-promises-is-there-a-way-to-kill-the-other-promises-once-anyone-is?noredirect=1#comment127938466_72421849):

The [`Promise` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) does not support cancellation. Therefore, you'll have to design a cancellation mechanism into your own API.

Here's a slight modification to the code in your question which does exactly that using the [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) API:

```js
let flag = false;

function PromiseA(abortSignal) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (abortSignal.aborted) {
        reject();
        return;
      }
      console.log(flag)
      flag = true;
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function PromiseB(abortSignal) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (abortSignal.aborted) {
        reject();
        return;
      }
      if (flag === true) {
        console.log('checking')
        console.log('flag is:' + flag)
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    }, 7000);
  });
}

async function main () {
  const ac = new AbortController();

  const promiseList = [
    PromiseA(ac.signal),
    PromiseB(ac.signal),
  ].map(p => p.then(() => ac.abort()));

  await Promise.any(promiseList);
  console.log('done');
}

main();
```

Comment: Thanks this helps, but will this instantly abort the PromiseB when PromiseA updates the signal? If not can we make that happen in any possible way?

Comment: Also why AbortController is a better way instead of declaring global variables?

Comment: @AbdullahKhilji (1) "_will this instantly abort the PromiseB when PromiseA updates the signal?_": No, it will only abort once the conditional statement is reached. (2) "_If not can we make that happen in any possible way?_": No. (3) "_why AbortController is a better way instead of declaring global variables?_": _Better_ is subjective. `AbortController` was designed for exactly this kind of scenario. You are free to use globals if you don't care about code reusability across module boundaries.