# stop promises to modify state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In my app I want to show files for different Items.
When item A is selected, it can take some time until it is loaded.
When in the meantime item B is selected, how can I stop the loading of item A?

Take this simplified example of my use case:

```js
<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'
const files = reactive([])

function load(item) {
  // reset files
  files.length = 0
  // simulate long running process with setTimeout
  setTimeout(() => {
    files.push(item)
  }, 5000)
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="load('A')">A</button>
  <button @click="load('B')">B</button>
  <pre>files: {{ files }}</pre>
</template>
```

When clicking the buttons A and B within less than 5seconds, the files list will show A and B eventually, but I want it to only show B.

My real use case is more complex and involves multiple state variables (not only `files`) and multiple Promises spawned in the background to populate these variables.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: hey mate, did you try with [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) or [Promise.any()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any)

Comment: The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233302/promise-is-it-possible-to-force-cancel-a-promise) has a lot of good info.

Comment: Although a simple solution (if you don't care about cancelling those api calls) would be to set a variable `lastCalled` in your data to some random data (a uuid maybe?) and then before populating `files`, check whether `lastCalled` is still set to what you set it as.