# How to abort a jQuery 3.0 AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, es6-promise, jquery-3

How to abort an AJAX request in jQuery 3.0?

```
this.r = $.ajax();
```

The promise does not have a abort method like in older jQuery versions

```
if(this.r && this.r.state() == 'pending')
{
  this.r.abort(); <- error not working
}
```

Comment: Let's try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request

Comment: That does not work in jquery 3.0. I tried! getting abort method is undefined

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery 3.0, jQuery.Deferred is Promises/A+ compatible. [The cancellation spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/cancellation-spec/issues) is still under development, so at this time it's not possible to abort an AJAX request.

Also see [Status of cancellable promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781434/status-of-cancellable-promises) for some background information regarding the spec.